# Combine these two SQL statements into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, sql-except

I have two tables `t1`, `t2` with columns `name, invoice, total`.

I am using this query to get the rows that in T2 and not in T1

```
select * 
from t2  
where name = (select source from info) 
except 
(select * from t1)
```

It works fine and returning a couple rows, what I want is to delete these returned rows in one statement.

I've tried this, but it deletes all the rows in T2 not only the returned rows from the query.

```
delete from t2 
where exists ((select * 
               from t2  
               where name = (select source from info) 
               except 
               (select * from t1) 
             ))
```

Here is a sample of my data:

T1

[image]

T2

[image]

THE RETURNED DATA (EXISTS IN T2 AND NOT IN T1 WHERE THE NAME IS C2)

[image]

The 3rd table info is get the name which is in this case is C2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some sample data from both table and then explain which rows you wants to delete. Also tag appropriate database name.

Comment: You say you have two tables but your query references three.

Comment: CHECK MY UPDATE, the 3rd table is to get the name of the local client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a left join of `t2` to `t1`:

```
delete t
from (
  select * from t2
  where name = (select source from info)
) t left join t1
on t1.name = t.name and t1.invoice = t.invoice and t1.total = t.total
where t1.name is null
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b9b82474b1df0eff5ac39a8ad518d6e).
If you want to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
delete t
from (
  select * from t2
  where name = (select source from info)
) t 
where not exists (
  select 1 from t1
  where name = t.name and invoice = t.invoice and total = t.total
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ecde51aa003bfc2e5f6216398ca088a).
Results (rows remaining in `t2`):

```
> name | invoice | total
> :--- | ------: | ----:
> C1   |       1 |   150
> C1   |       2 |   300
> C2   |       1 |   200
> C2   |       2 |   165
```

Comment: I'm really thankful, the first answer worked exactly as I want, thank you so much, just a question, why we use (where t1.name is null) can u explain this. and thanks again.

Comment: This is a left join of t2 to t1. If any row of t1 does not match any row of t1 then the value of t1.name and the other columns in that row will be null. This is the way to check that there is no match and this is what you want. To delete the rows form t2 that do not match a row in t1.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using this query to get the rows that in T2 and not in T1

The query that I would use is:

```
select t2.*
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.? = t2.name);
```

It is not clear what the name of the matching column is in `t1`.

This is readily turned into a `delete`:

```
delete from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.? = t2.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete from t2 with two conditions:

- name = (select source from info)
- row has no match in t1

The statement:

```
delete from t2
where name = (select source from info)
and not exists
(
  select *
  from t1
  where t1.name = t2.name
    and t1.invoice = t2.invoice
    and t1.total = t2.total
);
```

Or shorter with an `IN` clause, only available in DBMS that allow `IN` with tuples:

```
delete from t2
where name = (select source from info)
and (name, invoice, total) not in (select name, invoice, total from t1);
```